# ASUS PRIME H310M-E R2.0/CSM VX-t virtualization

Tags: virtualbox, motherboard, bios, virtualization, hardware-virtualization

I bought the motherboard ASUS PRIME H310M-E R2.0 and didn't even check if virtualization is possible with this motherboard. In the bios, I see VT-d and am able to enable that, but I don't see VT-x or Intel Virtualization Technology.

Is it possible that the motherboard doesn't support it? Can you recommend some micro-ATX motherboards/chipsets that would be able to support this feature?

My CPU is i5-9500, which should be able to support this without a problem.

Thank you very much for any help or advice!

Comment: Hardware virtualization is dependent on the CPU not the motherboard.  If you can enable VT-d then there is an option to enable VT-x (i.e. Intel Hardware Virtualization )  Without understanding what options you actually see it is difficult to indicate what you need to enable on your specific motherboard.

Comment: Do the VT-x settings here https://2nwiki.2n.cz/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=75202968  help you?  ASUS is on this page a bit farther down.